# Oracle sql condition issue

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle database i am have a value <null> in a column. I am trying to update null value in that column. below query is not helping me out.

```
update tbl set col=null where col is '<null>'
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the condition you are checking here?

Comment: `where col is null` - no quotes or angled brackets - but why would you set it to null if you have tested for null?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

```
UPDATE tbl SET COL = NULL WHERE COL = 'YOUR VALUE'
```

And the column should be null-able.